# MySQL Server won't start - [ERROR] COLLATION

Tags: mysql, vps, ubuntu-14.04

Ok, first, sorry for this question, I usually search a lot before post a question on any forum or Q&A.
But now I'm on panic, I need help (also to keep my job).  :)

This morning the server I manage who host many websites of clients of the company where I work had a problem.
The error when I try to visit one of the website is simply:

> Error establishing a database connection

First I've tried to login into plesk, but the error was the same (failed to connect to the DB)
So I tried to restart the entire VPS, but nothing to do the error still there, so I connected through ssh and I tried with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I check for the mysql logs and it was empty except for this:

> 160801 08:07:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql 160801  8:07:11 [Warning] Using unique option prefix
>   key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 160801 
>   8:07:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
>   starting as process 5448 ... 160801  8:07:11 [ERROR] COLLATION
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 160801 
>   8:07:11 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 160801  8:07:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 160801 08:07:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

I really don't know what happened but I think the problem could be that error in the log.

Comment: -1 ServerFault is a Q & A platform and not a forum. Even as the OP you can post  an answer and accept it as the solution. Please don't edit your and rename your question to include the answer

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, sorry, this morning I was a little bit in panic (I'm sure you know what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue in this way.

I've opened the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf with nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And I've commented this line:

> collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I tried to start the mysql again and now it works.

I don't know exactly why it happened, and I'm still investigating about.

I hope this could be helpful to someone else.